# Counting multiples of a factor in Python with return

Tags: python

What do I need to write after the return so that this function will count the multiples of a given factor?

```
def count_multiples(factor, maximum):

    return #number of multiples of 'factor' up to 'maximum'

count_multiples(3, 20) #for example
```

The function takes two integers as parameter:

- factor: which is the number I should calculate the multiples of.
- maximum: this is the maximum value that a multiple can have in order to be counted.

The function needs to return an integer value, which is the total number of multiples of factor greater than 0 and less than or equal to maximum.

In this case, the outcome needs to be: 6, because the numbers 3, 6, 9, 12, 15 and 18 are the multiples of 3 within the range 0 and 20.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: `len(range(factor, maximum, factor))` is concise. But you probably want to use modular arithmetic for anything larger like `20 // 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The pythonic way may be

   ```
   def count_multiples(factor, maximum):
       return len(range(factor, maximum + 1, factor))
   ```
2. but the arithmetic is the int division of the max by the factor :

   ```
   def count_multiples(factor, maximum):
       return maximum // factor
   ```

---

```
# To get
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(count_multiples(3, 20))  # 6
    print(count_multiples(3, 21))  # 7
```

Comment: Just out of interest, why is the first more pythonic? I don't think I really understand what pythonic means...

Comment: @Marses *pythonic* mostly refers to code that uses specific python method and operations, code that could not directly be written in another language, here using len and range

Answer (score 1):

```
return maximum // factor
```

Should give you what you want no? As in this will return the division without remainder, which is equal to the largest number you can multiply `factor` by such that the result is less than or equal to `maximum`. It will also return the right type (`int`).

Actually some of the comments already answered this before me.

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_multiples(factor, maximum):
    return int(maximum/factor)
count_multiples(3,20) # would give you '6' as output
```